# How to handle SIGSTOP/SIGCONT in a ptracer?

Tags: c, linux, ptrace

So I have a nice cooperative `PTRACE_TRACEME` child program being handled by a `PTRACE` wrapper program.

The problem is if the admin (or other) decides to `SIGSTOP` the child program, how can I handle that? And pick up the `SIGCONT` later, of course.

The answer might be *"you can't"*? This is `PTRACE`  after all!

I can see that `PTRACE_LISTEN` (since Linux 3.4) has a role to play, putting the child program in a stopped state, but that is documented to only work when the child is attached with `PTRACE_SEIZE`.

I have tried the trivial thing of calling `PTRACE_LISTEN` when in `PTRACE_TRACEME` mode in the Group-stop, and as documented I get the Old McDonald error - `EIO`.

I have a thought that I could inject code to do a `sigsuspend`, but of course that will only pause the 1 thread of the child program. I would have to inject a signal to every thread to then stop them all? And then restart?

Or perhaps the implementation of redelivered `SIGSTOP` has already stopped them all? In which case would my `sigsuspend` actually get triggered? I guess I could trigger it directly if another thread reported `SIGCONT`.

While this sounds like a lot of fun to code, I am wondering have I missed a trick in the `PTRACE` documentation? Perhaps there is a way to get to `PTRACE_SEIZE` compatibility mode that I am missing?

[more caviats]

**why not just use PTRACE_SEIZE in the first place?**

- PTRACE_TRACEME requires fewer security privileges;
- we use seccomp to filter down the syscall intercepts, which are the main point;
- we want to be in from the start of the child exe execution.

So to conclude: Is there a mechanism either to get to `PTRACE_SEIZE` mode or to simulate `SIGSTOP` behaviour within the API as it stands?

Answer (score 4):

An example **PTRACE_SEIZE** Test program that simulates SIGSTOP behavior follows.

```
#define PTRACE_SEIZE        0x4206
  #define PTRACE_SEIZE_DEVEL    0x80000000

  static const struct timespec ts100ms = { .tv_nsec = 100000000 };
  static const struct timespec ts1s = { .tv_sec = 1 };
  static const struct timespec ts3s = { .tv_sec = 3 };

  int main(int argc, char **argv)
  {
      pid_t tracee;

      tracee = fork();
      if (tracee == 0) {
          nanosleep(&ts100ms, NULL);
          while (1) {
              printf("tracee: alive\n");
              nanosleep(&ts1s, NULL);
          }
      }

      if (argc > 1)
          kill(tracee, SIGSTOP);

      nanosleep(&ts100ms, NULL);

      ptrace(PTRACE_SEIZE, tracee, NULL,
         (void *)(unsigned long)PTRACE_SEIZE_DEVEL);
      waitid(P_PID, tracee, NULL, WSTOPPED);
      ptrace(PTRACE_CONT, tracee, NULL, NULL);
      nanosleep(&ts3s, NULL);
      printf("tracer: exiting\n");
      return 0;
  }
```

When the above code is called without an argument, tracee is seized from
running state and continued.  When tracer exits, tracee is returned to
running state and keeps printing out.

```
 # ./test-seize
  tracee: alive
  tracee: alive
  tracee: alive
  tracer: exiting
  # tracee: alive
  tracee: alive
  tracee: alive
```

When called with an argument, tracee is seized from stopped state and
continued, and returns to stopped state when tracer exits.

```
    # ./test-seize
  tracee: alive
  tracee: alive
  tracee: alive
  tracer: exiting
  # ps -el|grep test-seize
  1 T     0  4720     1  0  80   0 -   941 signal ttyS0    00:00:00 test-seize
```

You can read more at this [thread](https://lore.kernel.org/patchwork/patch/250321/)

Comment: Yes, indeed, I can see that PTRACE_SEIZE  does provide the capability. I noted that in the question, and it is discussed in the public PTRACE documentation. But if I read that correctly, to use any of the break-in mechanisms other than PTRACE_TRACEME requires additional security privileges amongst other things. Also the question of whether the tracee can be stopped from the moment it is created?